# Qt TextEdit slow

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'd like to have rich text processing for large documents in Qt. The documentation says:

> QTextEdit is an advanced WYSIWYG viewer/editor supporting rich text formatting using HTML-style tags, or Markdown format. **It is optimized to handle large documents and to respond quickly to user input.**

However, both QTextEdit widget and TextEdit QML type seem to be slow. I opened official examples like [this one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html) and pasted hundreds of pages of rich text. I also did the same in Microsoft Word. As a result, operations on the text in QTextEdit got really slow while in Microsoft Word it's all fine.

So, is there a way to optimize allegedly optimized TextEdit (widget or QML type) in Qt? Or all the difference is due to Microsoft Wording working on just a visible part of the document while  TextEdit is not? To that end, could we reasonably use model/view with QTextEdit?

Comment: What do you mean by 'seem to be slow'? I'm currently trying it, I've added a lot of pages of rich text to the example but everything is fine. Which version of Qt are you using and on which platform?

Comment: I agree, pasting a lot of text in the example you stated is slow, but that is most likely because that particular example does some more processing on the pasted text before it is shown. Performance in large documents using the QML TextEdit element being bad [has been a known issue since at least 2014](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37872), but QTextEdit should not suffer from the same problem. Could you try [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html) example and see if it produces better performance for you?